# Is manipulating a trivial equality a logically valid proof of a formula?

Tags: group-theory, logic, proof-writing, solution-verification, dihedral-groups

I was working on a proof that $r^{n/2}$ commutes with $f$ in $D_4$. I did not know where to start, so I decided to manipulate a true statement into the formula I was trying to prove, as a sort of derivation.

$$\begin{align}
ef &= ef \\
r^nf &= r^0f \\ 
r^{n/2} r^{n/2} f &= r^{n/2} r^{-n/2} f \\
r^{n/2} f &= r^{-n/2} f \\
r^{n/2} f &= f r^{n/2} \\
\end{align} $$

However, I started second-guessing myself because I realized “$ef=ef$” is true always, regardless of whether “$r^{n/2}$ commutes with $f$” is true. This leads me wondering whether “$ef=ef \implies r^{n/2} f = f r^{n/2}$” is tautological and if, in general, if any implication beginning with a trivial equality is tautological.

Comment: I don't see how you got from $r^{n/2} f = r^{-n/2} f$ to 
$r^{n/2} f = f r^{n/2} $.

Comment: Because $r^kfr^kf=e$ so $fr^k=r^{-k}f$ (something I had proven earlier)

Comment: Ah, I see; thank you.

Comment: You may be thinking of vacuous truth, where any implication beginning with a false statement is tautological. In this case, every line must be true, either because it's the first line (a trivial equality), or because it follows from the truth of the previous line. Thus the last line must be true as well.

Comment: To directly address your final sentence: no, your stated implication is not tautological—nor does your working involve any [deductive explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) or [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implication $\top \Rightarrow P$ is equivalent to $P$ itself, so proving $\top\Rightarrow P$ does indeed prove $P$. (Here $\top$ denotes a proposition that is always true.)

However, after finding a proof this way, it is very common to rewrite it as a chain of equalities by reading your chain of implication on the LHS from bottom to top and then RHS from top to bottom:
$$\begin{align}
r^{n/2} f &= r^{-n/2} (r^n f)\\
& = r^{-n/2} (ef) \\
&= r^{-n/2} (r^0 f )\\
& = r^{-n/2} (r^{n/2} r^{-n/2}f)\\
& = r^{-n/2}f \\
&= fr^{n/2}.
\end{align}
$$
This chain then may be simplified a bit:
$$
r^{n/2} f =  r^{-n/2} r^n f = r^{-n/2} ef = r^{-n/2}f = fr^{n/2}.
$$

Comment: That answers the question. I’ll have to work on rewriting though, it’s not as self-apparent as I’d like it to be

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this technique is valid. It doesn't matter that $ef=ef$ is always true, since your list of equations works because it is assumed that each equation follows from the one above (and not necessarily *vice versa*).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $D_4=\langle r,s\mid r^4=e, s^2=e,srs^{-1}=e\rangle$, Then we have
$$
sr^2s^{-1}=r^{-2}=r^2,
$$
so $r^2$ commutes with $r$ and $s$ and hence with all elements. So it is in the center.

So you don't have to start with $ef=ef$, but it is not false.

Comment: The OP doesn't start with $ef=fe$.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, this was a typo.